# Is it slider, cycle, carousel?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010, slider, slideshow, image-rotation

I need something like this (http://www.thomasville.com/). The image rotator with nice faded text and the numbers for navigation. I did a view source and saw bunch of js. I dont want to use too many of those js as I have constrain what I can uplaod to our server. Can anyone point me to right direction and good sample where I can get something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try http://www.slidesjs.com/

Comment: @Gutierrezalex: this http://slidesjs.com/examples/images-with-captions/ is good but missing the numbering. I wanted number instead of clickable round buttons

Comment: But then how do you display numbers with link? Like the sample I posted

Comment: The numbers are behind the round buttons. If you edit the CSS file, you can get the numbers to show. You would need to know CSS

Comment: this is working and now i get the numbers. Last thing is move it where the caption is but align to right. 
.pagination li a { 
 bottom:-35px; 
 right:0;
 font-size:1.3em;

Comment: Man. Finally fixed the CSS to show the number style navigation on the right side. Thanks GutierrezAlex.

Answer (score 0):

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ is a pretty good jquery plugin for image slideshows. It has plenty of examples as well.

Comment: I couldnt find a sample/demo that caters my needs

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Galleria: http://galleria.aino.se/

It seems to be very full featured and can be customized as you need.

Comment: way 2 complicated. I am sure there are some good news slider with caption and navigation link yet less complicated. LOL

Comment: Plus you have to purchase the premium theme if you want to use additional funtionalities.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of modern jQuery sliders here
http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/ 
and here http://www.ajaxline.com/node/2130

Answer (score 0):

For your purposes can be helpful folowing slideshows

http://www.webanddesigners.com/15-jquery-slideshow-and-plugins/

http://graphicalerts.com/20-best-jquery-slideshow-image-photo-gallery-plugins/